# Mapstruct transform obect to list

Tags: mapstruct

I have to map an object to list of another objects like below

public List map(ClassA A){

```
 List<ClassB> list = new ArrayList<ClassB>();
 ClassB C1 = new ClassB();
  ClassB C2= new ClassB();
```

.... Logic to populate C1 and C2 from ClassA
add C1 and C2 to list

return list;

}

In the generated Impl class, I am getting a complilation error "Cannot find the symbol ClassB". The class "ClassB" is not imported to the generated impl class. Please help me in solving this.

Comment: Please, provide your mapper, ClassA and ClassB!

Answer (score 0):

MapStruct cannot generate mapping methods between iterable types (`List<ClassB>`) and non-iterable types (`ClassA`).

Can you share the definitions of `ClassA` and `ClassB` in more detail? Then we can try and find a good solution. Probably it's simplest though to just implement this one from hand (esp. if `ClassA` contains a list of `ClassB`, in which case no mapping for the list elements is required).